# 'Variable is never used' warning in android studio

Tags: android

i have created a button(id- btnBank).
But there is waraning of variable 'btnBank'is never used.

code in activity_maps.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bank" />
```

code in MapsActivity.java

Button btnBank = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBank);

```
    btnRestaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String Bank = "bank";
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
            mMap.clear();
            String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Bank);
            Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
            DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            DataTransfer[1] = url;
            Log.d("onClick", url);
            GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
            getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Bank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

In first line of java code 'btnBank' appears grey

Comment: You never used the btnBank you just assign its view. If you use your btnBank such as btnBank.setOnClickListener it won't appear grey.

Answer (score 1):

Because btnBank you never use it. Otherwise would not it show you the warning. In this code you do not use that variable. Only you use btnRestaurant.

Answer (score 0):

just add
btnBank=null; in your on create method, because its not set to anything , which is giving you the error

Answer (score 0):

The code you apply is about **btnRestaurant**, but what the IDE warns is about **btnBank**. Remember that method **findViewById** doesn't belong to usage of a view.